# How i can decode string to the json?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have an array. Inside of which are strings that need to be converted into JSON arrays and then access them and display the data. I have every time showing NULL
http://prntscr.com/ojx5jv

```
    $array =  get_user_meta(  $cur_user_id, 'json' );
    var_dump($array);

     foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<dt>$key:</dt>";
        echo "<dd>$value</dd>";
        $arr = (json_decode(($value), true));
        var_dump($arr);

     }
```

I already asked such a question. I got it wrong

first dump line 2

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '"{"cards1":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZGLu012aTOT",null],"cards2":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZVEIDOT",null],"cards3":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","ATBALSTu012aT",null]}"' (length=201)
  1 => string '"{"cards1":["RADOu0160u0100S PRASMES","IZMAINu012aT",null],"cards2":["RADOu0160u0100S PRASMES","IZPILDu012aT",null],"cards3":["RADOu0160u0100S PRASMES","PLu0100NOT",null]}"' (length=172)
  2 => string '"{"cards1":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","NOTEIKT",null],"cards2":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZSKAIDROT",null],"cards3":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZVEIDOT",null]}"' (length=193)
  3 => string '"{"cards1":["NOTEIKT",null],"cards2":["IZVEIDOT",null],"cards3":["IZSKAIDROT",null]}"' (length=85)
```

second dump

```
0:
"{"cards1":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZGLu012aTOT",null],"cards2":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZVEIDOT",null],"cards3":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","ATBALSTu012aT",null]}"
C:\wamp64\www\wordpress.game\wp-content\plugins\WPgame Custom Plugin\WPcafe-custom-plugin.php:82:null
1:
"{"cards1":["RADOu0160u0100S PRASMES","IZMAINu012aT",null],"cards2":["RADOu0160u0100S PRASMES","IZPILDu012aT",null],"cards3":["RADOu0160u0100S PRASMES","PLu0100NOT",null]}"
C:\wamp64\www\wordpress.game\wp-content\plugins\WPgame Custom Plugin\WPcafe-custom-plugin.php:82:null
2:
"{"cards1":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","NOTEIKT",null],"cards2":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZSKAIDROT",null],"cards3":["Mu0100Cu012au0160ANu0100S PRASMES","IZVEIDOT",null]}"
C:\wamp64\www\wordpress.game\wp-content\plugins\WPgame Custom Plugin\WPcafe-custom-plugin.php:82:null
3:
"{"cards1":["NOTEIKT",null],"cards2":["IZVEIDOT",null],"cards3":["IZSKAIDROT",null]}"
C:\wamp64\www\wordpress.game\wp-content\plugins\WPgame Custom Plugin\WPcafe-custom-plugin.php:82:null
```

Comment: What is the result of your var_dump() on line 2?

Comment: On the topmost screen http://prntscr.com/ojx5jv

Comment: Can you post the dumps as text here? It makes it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I made it. I update my question

Comment: It looks as though you have `"` round the JSON string

Comment: According to the first dump, you may have some extra quotes on your values. Try `json_decode(trim($value, '"'), true);`

Comment: Thanks you very match. Thanks thanks thanks

Comment: And you do not tell me. I have an encoding problem there. When I entered the data into my created table, everything was also saved there (well, with corrupted simols), but then I also output and it output with normal encoding, and here it is broken and output. How can I fix this?